Can 'wiedergut' function as a "Verbpartikel"
I can find no indication of what happens with 'wiedergutmachen' in the Present tense. 'Ich mache es wiedergut' seems unlikely, but 'Ich mache es wieder gut' begs the question about the status of 'gut': is it (still?) a kind of Verbpartikel, even though it is no longer part of 'wiedergut', which looks like a Verbpartikel in the infinitive (with or without 'zu'), in the past participle and with the verb at the end of a subordinate clause?

It is "Ich mache es wieder gut." as you can see in Duden in the Rechtschreibung and the Grammatik section. Duden chooses to explain grammar by example.
As you noted correctly, wieder gut is not a common particle and does not form a single, semantic unit. This is why it has to be written apart. Furthermore, it is a combination of adverb wieder with adjective gut, which would usually not be written together.
This mirrors the behavior in other cases, where all words are written together once combined, but apart when one part is missing. Take for example Nachhauseweg vs. Weg nach Hause. Even though the shift in meaning in Hause from house to home is the same, they only get combined with Weg.
On a side note, the meaning of wiedergutmachen ist just a little bit different from wieder gut machen, which is why it used to be written apart from 1996 to 2006 according to korrekturen.de.

So: is 'Er wollte es wieder gutmachen' possible and does/would it mean something different from 'Er wollte es wiedergutmachen' ?!

@Bernhard Yes, it is possible. In theory, it would mean "make up for something again". In practice, many hits for "gutmachen" in DWDS as well as the example in duden use "wieder gutmachen" with the same meaning as "wiedergutmachen".

"wiedergutmachen" is actually Präsens (present tense). "gut" is just an Adverb, like in "schwarzmalen" (about: to doomsay, literal: to blackpaint) or "hartlöten" (to braze, to hard-solder). German verbs, if composite verbs are built, are not limited to combinations with certain word sorts.
If you insist on taking apart the verb it is more likely "wieder-gutmachen" than "wiedergut-machen". The "gut" and the "machen" are first coupled and only then the "wieder" is added. A literal translation would be "again - make - good", hence: to make up, to atone for.
The past participle is "wiedergutgemacht", analogous to "machen-gemacht". The "ge-" was originally a prefix to mark perfectiveness (that is: an action has a change of state as a result) and was productive in Middle High German, only now it is lexicalised and (only) used as a past participle marker. This is why it can sometimes appear after certain particles (like: "einkaufen - eingekauft" and not "geeinkauft").

Sorry, bakunin, but why confuse particles with prefixes? they can stand alone, are "fixed" only sometimes and are often not 'pre' anything. the 'ge' is part of the pp' gekauft' before a particle is added to it. Introducing a real prefix gets rid of the 'ge' (verkauft) but we can still add a particle (ausverkauft)!

@Bernhard: I haven't "confused particles with prefixes", I have - as an additional information - added the reason why some (actually: most) verbs in German build their past participle with "ge-". This, btw., was the case with Middle and Old English as well, as was the case with Gothic (were it was "ga-").
